# Math in SQL Server 2008 : rounding and truncating

Tags: sql-server-2008

I m looking for basic SQL query in SQL Server 2008

```
number   Result 
-----    ------
 0.38     0        (As it is less than 0.5)
 2.66     3        (As it is more than 2.5)
 3.8      4        (As it is more than 3.5)
 11.97    12       (As it is more than 11.50)
```

I'm not getting how to get it fix for using trunc, floor and other such method

Any help would be helpful.

Thanks !!!!

Comment: `SELECT ROUND(0.38,0),ROUND(2.66,0),ROUND(3.8,0),ROUND( 11.97,0)`?

Comment: Thanks , it was such a simple thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something similar to this:

```
SELECT number, ROUND(number,0) as Result FROM Table_name
```

check this [SQL ROUND()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp) Function and [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) for more info.